# How do you fix npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

### How do you fix this problem?

[Nodejs npm and npx problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D9Qv.png)

When i trying to install or check anything on command prompt. Node js through

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead

this error. For instance what can i do. I have little knowledge about node js if any one have any solution please help me.

Answer (score 18):

My solution to solve this problem:

1. Go to C:\Program Files\nodejs
2. Edit 4 files named npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd
3. Open files in VS Code
4. Replace prefix -g with prefix --location=global in all four files
5. Save all (if asked save as admin)

Good to go!

Answer (score 6):

I see from your screenshot you are using npm ver 8.11.0.
I believe the error you are seeing was an issue on that version, and it was fixed on npm ver [8.12.1](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.12.1)

Can you try updating your npm to the most recent version?
That should solve the warning.

Comment: hmm.. `npm update -g npm` fails with the same error as the one to be fixed.. May be we can update it with `yarn` (or `nvm-windows`)?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. 
But I believe how each person will update their npm depends on how they manage their node/npm installs. 
There are many possibilities to do it: yarn, nvm-windows, nodist, or even downloading node installer.

Answer (score 3):

npm has fixed this and all you need to do is update your npm version:

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

Comment: This did not work for me (running Windows10 cygwin bash shell on windows npm version 9.6.4) Node 16.15.1

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

1. Go to the node.js installation folder, eg. `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. open `npm.cmd` with notepad **as admin**
3. Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global`, and Save
4. Do the same for `npx.cmd`

Check if it is fixed

If it is not working, update `npm` using `npm install npm@latest -g`

[image: A screenshot for modifying the file]

Answer (score 2):

I did not like the answers that involved editing the NPM source scripts (npm.cmd).

When running `npm --version` I shouldn't get a warning as I haven't used the `-g` option.

```
npm --version
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.11.0
```

This was with node version 16.15.1.

So I searched for a solution and came up with the use of **node v18.6.0 along with npm v8.13.2**

I used these commands:

```
nvm install 18.6.0
nvm use 18.6.0
node -v && npm -v
v18.6.0
8.13.2
```

### Details of how I found this answer.

Things I was interested in:

1. What was the root of this problem?
2. What version of npm did this warning start appearing in.
3. I'm using `nvm` (technically [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)) so I should be able to switch to a version of node/npm that work properly together.

I searched for an answer to the root cause of this problem and learned (from [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xEgFfpUeEs)):

1. npm version 8.11.0 has the problem (warning).  [See bug in github issues for npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5228). NOTE: I never found the exact commit that introduced the warning.
2. npm version 8.13.1 fixes the problem by removing the deprecated warning.

So I needed to find the `nvm` version to install that includes `npm 8.13.1` or higher. I found https://nodejs.org/de/download/releases/ which shows that `Node.js v18.6.0` uses `npm v8.13.2`

So I installed that version of node (using nvm) and this fixed the problem (without editing any of the `npm.cmd`, `npx.cmd`, etc files).

The commands I used were:

```
nvm install 18.6.0
nvm use 18.6.0
node -v && npm -v
v18.6.0
8.13.2
```

Now, I don't get a warning when running the `npm -v` command.

Answer (score 0):

### Backend Rule Now Gonna Solve npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead

I think your Node.js command prompt is throwing this error to you don't worry I'll fix this error ► [Node.js CMD Prompt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gwl9.png)

First of all open you c drive and explore your program file after that open node js folder.

Please look at this picture. This picture tells you a lot►
[Node.js Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiOWi.png)

Now you have to do open vs code or any code editor as a administrator ►
[In this image i explain which two file you need to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktX77.png)

Okay now change npm file line number 23 prefix-g to prefix --location=global

View this image it's help you to understand ►
[How can you change npm prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJL0Q.png)

Now you have to change another one npm.cmd file prefix

open npm.cmd file on your code editor and change line no 12 prefix-g to prefix --location=global

This image explain how can do this ► [Change npm.cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yICzB.png)

### If you have same problem in your npx then follow my instruction

1st open your npx file on your code editor ► [Select This Two File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1c8m.png)

2nd Now start edit with only npx file like that ► [npx file prefix set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoCZq.png)

3rd Now start edit npx.cmd file like that ► [npx cmd prefix set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uOGB.png)

Answer (score -1):

how I can fix this error please for Mac : npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.