# npm update fails from 8.4.0 to 8.11.0

Tags: node.js, npm, chocolatey

I AM RUNNING NODE.JS AND NPM ON WINDOWS!

I newly installed the newest LTS release of Node.js (v16.15.1) which is supposed to contain npm version of 8.11.0.

I've installed the Windows package and executed all of the chocolatey scripts as recommended.

But when I run `npm -v` I get the following output:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.4.0
```

Any idea how to fix this?

I already tried running `choco upgrade all`.

The older version causes issues for me, I also tried restarting the machine.

Comment: Did you check this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72674740/how-do-you-fix-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use

Comment: @Alasgar thanks that solved one of my problems. I ran `npm update npm -g` for the second problem, now npm is a bit newer than it's supposed to be...